# Injection of ConsumeContext into scoped object

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

I'm trying to setup some scoped object and inject `ConsumeContext` into it in order to use it late from the instance in order to send some messages.

Here is how I'm trying to achieve it

First of all `ScopedObject`

```
public class ScopedObject
{
    public Guid ScopeId { get; set; } = NewId.NextGuid();

    private ConsumeContext _context;

    public void SetContext(ConsumeContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task DoSomeStaff()
    {
        if (_context == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(_context));

        //  publish message to bus using _context here... 

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

then I prepared `InjectContextFilter` that just resolve the `ScopedObject` and inject `ConsumeContext` into it

```
public class InjectContextFilter : IFilter<ConsumeContext>
{
    private IServiceProvider _container;

    public InjectContextFilter(IServiceProvider container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext context, IPipe<ConsumeContext> next)
    {
        try
        {
            var scoped = _container.GetRequiredService<ScopedObject>();

            if (scoped != null)
            {
                scoped.SetContext(context);
            }

            await next.Send(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        var scope = context.CreateFilterScope("cqrslite");
    }
}
```

setup MassTransit

```
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddScoped<ScopedObject>();

        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<DoSomeWorkConsumer>();
        });

        services.AddSingleton(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
        {
            IRabbitMqHost host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://guest:guest@localhost:5672/test"), h => { });

            x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, $"receiver_queue", e =>
            {
                e.UseContextInjection(container);

                e.LoadFrom(container);
            });

            x.UseSerilog();
        }));

        container = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var busControl = container.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>();
```

and later in the consumer I want to get access to `ScopedObject` and expect to have `ConsumeContext` already injected there

```
public class DoSomeWorkConsumer : IConsumer<DoSomeWork>
{
    private ScopedObject _scoped;

    public DoSomeWorkConsumer(ScopedObject scoped)
    {
        _scoped = scoped ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scoped));
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<DoSomeWork> context)
    {
        await _scoped.DoSomeStaff();
    }
}
```

but in reality `_context` is `null`. The reason why it happened because my `InjectContextFilter` triggered before the the scope was created in `ScopeConsumerFactory<TConsumer>`, so, I did injection out of the scope that used in consumer.

My question is how to apply my InjectContextFilter after  `ScopeConsumerFactory<TConsumer>`? Or how to inject `ConsumeContex` into scoped object any other way?

Demo code available [here](https://github.com/pshenichnov/MassTransitScoping)

**SOLUTION**

Working demo is [here](https://github.com/pshenichnov/MassTransitScoping)

Comment: If you could figure out how to add registrations to the scope when it's created, this entire problem would go away since ConsumeContext could be registered within the scope, just as it is for Autofac and StructureMap. Short answer to your question, you'd need a filter on `ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, T>`, not just `ConsumeContext`.

Comment: Ok, I was able to setup filter  `IFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>>` and specification `IPipeSpecification<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>>` but can't figure out how to get `IPipeConfigurator<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>>` configurator in order to apply the filter. Could you point me to the code how to do that?

Comment: I cannot understand your request. If _scoped.DoSomeStaff is work before or after Consume operation, IConsumeObserver can be implemented. If your _scoped.DoSomeStaff is work at the middle of consume operation, probably it is your business code and ConsumeContext object pass a parameter for DoSomeStaff function.

Can you explain your business requirement? If I understand your needs, I want to try help.

Comment: @AdemCatamak, it's not a question about business code. It's a question how to properly inject `ConsumeContext` into any scoped object in order to use it later inside the instance. `_scoped.DoSomeStaff()` is just an example... it's not related to any particular project. I don't want to pass `ConsumeContext` into `_scoped.DoSomeStaff()` as a parameter. What if this `DoSomeStaff()` method is interface implementation and I can't change the notation?

Comment: `x.Consumer<T>(cfg => cfg.UseFilter(yourFilter))` should do it.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPatterson, thanks much for all you suggestion! Appreciate it a lot! But I'm still straggling... `x.Consumer<T>(cfg => cfg.UseFilter(yourFilter))` allows to apply filter inherited from `IFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer>>`. In order to apply filter inherited from `IFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TConsumer, TMessage>>` I do this `e.Consumer(container.GetRequiredService<DoSomeWorkConsumer>, cfg => cfg.ConsumerMessage<DoSomeWork>(m => m.UseFilter(new InjectContextFilter<DoSomeWorkConsumer, DoSomeWork>(container))));` and it kinda works but only for `e.PrefetchCount = 1;`

Comment: If change `PrefetchCount` to something else it starts working not quite I want... in this case all first `PrefetchCount` messages share the very first created `ScopedObject`. I think that it happens because of when I register consumer using `x.Consumer(...)` it's not using the `ScopeConsumerFactory`, so I tried to change it a bit and explicitly require to use `ScopeConsumerFactory` - `e.Consumer(new ScopeConsumerFactory<DoSomeWorkConsumer>(scopeProvider), cfg => cfg.ConsumerMessage<DoSomeWork>(m => m.UseFilter(new InjectContextFilter<DoSomeWorkConsumer, DoSomeWork>(container))));`

Comment: You are using this package, right? https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection/4.1.0.1463-develop  -- it has the consumer factory registration methods so you can specify your service provider for the factory.

Comment: ... so, now I can see that my filter triggered right after `ScopeConsumerFactory.Send` method, so it's inside the newly created scope, but in this case I can't get access to the `IServiceScope` from the filter in order to resolve the `ScopedObject` and inject `ConsumerContext`.

Comment: Yes, I do use MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection package

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson, I think I got it working!